# Solving for a differential equation when the function is non-negative

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-explanation

I have that $y$ is a non-negative function of $t$ and is described by the differential equation
$$ 
\frac{dy}{dt} = - \sqrt{y}
$$
and the initial condition is $y(0) = 1$. It seems to me that I can "separate variables," but the second I do, I need to assume that $y \neq 0$ because I can't divide by $\sqrt{y}$ otherwise, which undermines the initial condition. I know that the formula whereby I separate variables is a disguised version of the chain rule, but I think the formula would still need to be valid. Nonetheless, here is my attempt.

> If $y = 0$, then $\frac{dy}{dt} = 0$ so $y$ is any constant. Suppose $y \neq 0$. Rearranging, we get
> $$ 
> \frac{dy}{- \sqrt{y}} = dt. 
> $$
> Integrating, we get
> $$ 
> - 2 \sqrt{y} = t + C.
> $$
> At this step, I believe I need to place a restriction on $C$. If I rearrange, I get
> $$ 
> \sqrt{y} = \frac{t+C}{-2}.
> $$
> But $\sqrt{y} \geq 0$, so $\frac{t+C}{-2} \geq 0$. The denominator is negative, so it must be the case that $t+C$ is negative. So I must have $t+C <0$, so $t < C$. This doesn't make sense to me, because $t$ is allowed to be any non-negative real number in this problem. I may need to break the solution into two more cases, but this doesn't seem to be defined for $t > C$.
>
> I then square both sides to get:
> $$
> y = \frac{(t+C)^2}{4}. 
> $$
> Now I apply the initial condition, though I'm not certain I can since I assumed $y \neq 0$ earlier.
> $$
> y(0) = 1 = \frac{(0+C)^2}{4} = \frac{C^2}{4}.
> $$
> So $4 = C^2$ so $C = \pm 2$. I'm not sure which of these values of $C$ to choose.

Based on this attempt, I have three main questions:

1. Am I correct to assume $y \neq 0$ to divide by $\sqrt{y}$, and if so, how can I apply the initial condition?
2. Am I correct to impose a condition on $C$ based on nonnegativity of $\sqrt{y}$?
3. I can't figure out which value of $C$ to choose or how to break apart the solution into cases based on the condition $t < C$.

Answer (score 1):

Compute the constant earlier, where you introduce it
$$
-2\sqrt{1}=0+C\implies C=-2.
$$

The thus computed solution is valid indeed only as long as $y>0$. Now consider $y=0$ at $t=2$ as a new IVP for $t\ge 2$. Then obviously the constant-zero function is a solution. So in total
$$
y(t)=\frac{\max(2-t,0)^2}4
$$
is a solution that is defined for all $t>0$.

Comment: I appreciate the answer. What I don't understand is, if the solution is only valid for $y > 0$, why can we plug in the initial condition where $y = 0$?I'm also struggling to see where the initial condition $(2,0)$ comes from.

Comment: The solution method "separation of variables" is only valid for $y>0$. But obviously $y\equiv 0$ is a solution of the original equation.

Comment: Ok, so my understanding is that the solution $y = \frac{(t-2)^2}{4}$ is a valid solution for $t \leq 2$, and by plugging in $t =2$, we get $y = 0$. But what happens when $t > 2$?

Comment: Then $y=0$, it is a stable equilibrium, once reached the solution is caught in it.

Comment: I apologize for my ignorance, but how do you know this to be the case? I'm struggling to understand this.