# Solving a differential equation and understanding behavior of equilibrium points

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-explanation

I'm trying to understand how to solve the differential equation
$$ 
\frac{dx}{dt} = - \sqrt{x}, \; x(0) = 1, \; x(t) \geq 0 \text{ for all $t \geq 0$.}
$$
The solution the instructor gave is
$$
x(t) = \begin{cases}
\frac{(t-2)^2}{4} & \text{ if $t \leq 2$}  \\
0 & \text{ if $t \geq 2$.}
\end{cases}
$$
I am stuck with the case that $t \geq 2$. When I separate variables and use the initial condition, I find that $x(t) = \frac{(t-2)^2}{4}$ when $t \leq 2$.  When I plug in $t = 2$, I find $x(2) = 0$. I can also see from the original differential equation that if $x > 0$, $\frac{dx}{dt} < 0$, so $x = 0$ is a "stable" equilibrium point.

Here is my problem: I do not know how to tie $x = 0$ being a stable equilibrium to the case where $t \geq 2$. It seems that there is no connection to specific values of $t$ because I've only plugged in a value of $x$, not a value of $t$, and I have no other information about how $x(t)$ depends on $t$.

Can someone help me to understand this relationship?

Comment: Please cite also the previous discussions on this same IVP as context, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4525749/115115 and https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4527462/115115

Answer (score 0):

This so defined $x(t)$ is continuously differentiable, its derivative is
$$
x'(t)=\begin{cases}
\frac{t-2}2,&t\le 2\\ 0,&t>2.
\end{cases}
$$
The square root of it is
$$
\sqrt{x(t)}=\begin{cases}
\frac{2-t}2,&t\le 2\\ 0,&t>2,
\end{cases}
$$
so that indeed $x'(t)=-\sqrt{x(t)}$. So it is a solution. There is nothing more required.

---

When solving the equation you first detect that it is separable. Then check where division-by-zero occurs, and if these curves can be solutions. In this case indeed $x\equiv 0$ is a solution. Then check smoothness, the right side is not smooth, so uniqueness is not automatic there. However for $x\ne 0$ the right side is smooth, so one has to care for anything after finding the solution there with any means.

$x\equiv 0$ is the singular solution of the more general DE $(x')^2=x$. The derivative of this equation is $x'(2x''-1)=0$. Any solution can be divided into segments where one or the other factor is zero. At the intersections both factors have to be zero simultaneously (along with continuity etc.).

With the original equation the first equation gives $x=0$, the second $2x'=t+c\implies 4x=(t+c)^2$, intersections are only possible at $t=-c$. With the fixed sign and reduced domain of the given equation, the family of possible solutions reduces accordingly.

Comment: I'm struggling to understand the distinction you made, even in the definition of $x'(t)$, for $t \leq 2$ and $t > 2$.

Comment: Do you understand the idea of a piecewise defined function? Write it as $\frac14\max(0,\,2-t)^2$ for a more compact expression.

Comment: I understand the piece-wise function. I just don't understand where the second piece $x(t) = 0$ for $t > 2$ comes from. I'm very sorry for my ignorance on this. It's just not making sense to me.

Comment: @Cardinality: Since $x$ is supposed to be nonincreasing and nonnegative, what else can it do when it reaches zero other than stay there forever?

Comment: @Cardinality when $x(t)$ is zero, what is the value of the derivative in the differential equation and what does it imply for the future values of the state?

Comment: @KBS : Without uniqueness (local Lipschitz condition) there is no implication for future (or past) values. Modifying the equation to $x'=-\sqrt{|x|}$ gives the same equation for $x\ge 0$ but the solution now can branch out downwards at any point $t\ge 2$.

Comment: @LutzLehmann This does not have much to do with what I am saying. I am trying to explain to the OP what happens to the solution of the dynamical system, as obtained by separating the variables, when the time goes past the point $t=2$. If we follow that solution, it goes negative after $t=2$, which is not allowed here. But when we plug the zero state value in the dynamical system, this returns zero, which means that, when the state reaches zero, then the only possibility is that the state stays at zero for all $t\ge2$.